# How to handle print preview pop-up using selenium and Java. Alert and window handles aren't working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

I want to confirm that the print preview is opened and then close the dialog box.

```
Alert alert = getDriver().switchTo().alert();
    alert.dismiss();
    Set<String> allWindowHandles = getDriver().getWindowHandles();
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to solve this?

Comment: Is the URL public , so we can access?